# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/criterion/Criterion

Tags: java, mysql, spring-mvc, tomcat, tomcat7

I am working with STS in eclipse Juno ,Spring 3.1.1 ,hibernate 4.1, tomcat 7 and mySQL.

I created a simple MVC template project. my purpose is that the user will enter some data to a form, and that data will
be saved in the database.

I have created:

**web layer:**

1. the simple form.
2. the controller which recieve the data from the form and pass it to the service layer.

**service layer:**

a service class which contains a DAO field and operate a dao method.

**data access layer:**

1. A mock DAO implementation which doesn't commincate with the database.
2. A Real  DAO implementation which doesn commincate with the database.

When i checked the system with the mock DAO implementation, everything was OK - going from the web layer to the mock DAO.

but when injected the real DAO, i just got an 404 error, and nothing in the happened in the Database.

I will show only the DAO implementation and the  root-context.xml because this is where i think the problem.

My DAO Implementation:

```
@Repository
public class Presentation_page_dao_hibernate_Impl implements Presentation_page_dao {

    private  SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    public Presentation_page_dao_hibernate_Impl(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory=sessionFactory;
        System.out.println("Hi! i'm in ActionDao_HibernateImpl constructor");
        }

    private Session currentSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }


    public void create(Presentation_page pp) {  
        currentSession().beginTransaction();
        currentSession().save(pp);
        currentSession().getTransaction().commit();
        currentSession().close();       
    }


    public Presentation_page read(int pageid) throws PresentationPageNotFoundException {


        currentSession().beginTransaction();

        Criteria criteria=currentSession().createCriteria(Presentation_page.class);

        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("page_id", pageid));
        List<Presentation_page> list_of_pages=criteria.list();

        currentSession().getTransaction().commit();
        currentSession().close();

        for(Presentation_page pp:list_of_pages) {
            if (pp.getPage_id()==pageid){
                return pp;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void update(Presentation_page pp) throws PresentationPageNotFoundException {

        currentSession().beginTransaction();
        currentSession().update(pp);
        currentSession().getTransaction().commit();
        currentSession().close();   

    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Presentation_page  pp) throws PresentationPageNotFoundException {

        currentSession().beginTransaction();
        currentSession().delete(pp);
        currentSession().getTransaction().commit();
        currentSession().close();
    }

}
```

This is my root-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">    

    <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->


    <!-- For annotations -->
    <context:component-scan 
        base-package="my.topLevel.pack">
    </context:component-scan> 

    <import resource="hibernate2.xml"/>


</beans>
```

This is my hibernate.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring_presentation</property>
        <property name="connection.username">rotemya</property>
        <property name="connection.password">*******</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Enable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property> 


        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

        <!-- Names the annotated entity class -->
        <mapping class="my.topLevel.pack.Domain"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I have the following dependencies to the pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>my.topLevel</groupId>
    <artifactId>pack</artifactId>
    <name>SpringSTS_Sample_Project</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.6</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.13</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

This are my hibernate jar files:

[image]

I'm getting the following error:

**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/criterion/Criterion**

Any ideas?

Comment: Post your statck error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok-problem solved!

I removed all the jars from the hibernate library file (which i created), and add them all via Maven (the pom.xml file). and the error was gone..